# IOS: UIScrollViewDelegate not working

Tags: ios, scrollview

I used the following code to init the new UIScrollView:

```
    UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
```

Then I added 3 UIView instance into the scrollView instance.

But When I use it's delegate method - (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
 and - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

both of them did not work, I typed a NSLog Method to catch the logs in GDB if the functions calld.

What's going on?

Comment: Have you set the delegate class correctly?

Answer (score 2):

add your self as delegate of the UIScrollView

```
scroll.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add this code in viewdidload

```
ScrollView.delegate = self;
```

or link from storyboard/xib

and remember to add UIScrollViewDelegate after interface

```
@interface ViewController ()<UIScrollViewDelegate>

@end
```